# CLASSPATH error while configuring JAVA Environment (Java Development Kit)

Tags: bash, java, lfs

After installing JAVA(JDK) whenever I reboot the system or switch to normal user a message is displayed:

`bash: ${AUTO_CLASSPATH_DIR}: invalid variable name`

`bash: ${AUTO_CLASSPATH_DIR}: invalid variable name`

This is the configuration script

```
cat > /etc/profile.d/openjdk.sh << "EOF"
# Begin /etc/profile.d/openjdk.sh

# Set JAVA_HOME directory
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk

# Adjust PATH
pathappend $JAVA_HOME/bin

# Add to MANPATH
pathappend $JAVA_HOME/man MANPATH

# Auto Java CLASSPATH: Copy jar files to, or create symlinks in, the
# /usr/share/java directory. Note that having gcj jars with OpenJDK 8
# may lead to errors.

AUTO_CLASSPATH_DIR=/usr/share/java

pathprepend . CLASSPATH

for dir in `find ${AUTO_CLASSPATH_DIR} -type d 2>/dev/null`; do
    pathappend $dir CLASSPATH
done

for jar in `find ${AUTO_CLASSPATH_DIR} -name "*.jar" 2>/dev/null`; do
    pathappend $jar CLASSPATH
done

export JAVA_HOME
unset AUTO_CLASSPATH_DIR dir jar

# End /etc/profile.d/openjdk.sh
EOF
```

This is the output of `bash -xv /etc/profile.d/openjdk.sh`

```
pathappend () { pathremove $1 $2;
local PATHVARIABLE=${2:-PATH};
export $PATHVARIABLE="${!PATHVARIABLE:+${!PATHVARIABLE}:}$1"
}
pathprepend () { pathremove $1 $2;
local PATHVARIABLE=${2:-PATH};
export $PATHVARIABLE="$1${!PATHVARIABLE:+:${!PATHVARIABLE}}"
}
pathremove () { local IFS=':';
local NEWPATH;
local DIR;
local PATHVARIABLE=${2:-PATH};
for DIR in ${!PATHVARIABLE};
do
if [ "$DIR" != "$1" ]; then
NEWPATH=${NEWPATH:+$NEWPATH:}$DIR;
fi;
done;
export $PATHVARIABLE="$NEWPATH"
}
# Begin /etc/profile.d/openjdk.sh

# Set JAVA_HOME directory
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk
+ JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk

# Adjust PATH
pathappend $JAVA_HOME/bin
+ pathappend /opt/jdk/bin
+ pathremove /opt/jdk/bin
+ local IFS=:
+ local NEWPATH
+ local DIR
+ local PATHVARIABLE=PATH
+ for DIR in ${!PATHVARIABLE}
+ '[' /bin '!=' /opt/jdk/bin ']'
+ NEWPATH=/bin
+ for DIR in ${!PATHVARIABLE}
+ '[' /usr/bin '!=' /opt/jdk/bin ']'
+ NEWPATH=/bin:/usr/bin
+ for DIR in ${!PATHVARIABLE}
+ '[' /opt/jdk/bin '!=' /opt/jdk/bin ']'
+ export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
+ PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
+ local PATHVARIABLE=PATH
+ export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/jdk/bin
+ PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/jdk/bin

# Add to MANPATH
pathappend $JAVA_HOME/man MANPATH
+ pathappend /opt/jdk/man MANPATH
+ pathremove /opt/jdk/man MANPATH
+ local IFS=:
+ local NEWPATH
+ local DIR
+ local PATHVARIABLE=MANPATH
+ for DIR in ${!PATHVARIABLE}
+ '[' /usr/share/man '!=' /opt/jdk/man ']'
+ NEWPATH=/usr/share/man
+ for DIR in ${!PATHVARIABLE}
+ '[' opt/jdk/man '!=' /opt/jdk/man ']'
+ export MANPATH=/usr/share/man
+ MANPATH=/usr/share/man
+ local PATHVARIABLE=MANPATH
+ export MANPATH=/usr/share/man:/opt/jdk/man
+ MANPATH=/usr/share/man:/opt/jdk/man

# Auto Java CLASSPATH: Copy jar files to, or create symlinks in, the
# /usr/share/java directory. Note that having gcj jars with OpenJDK 8
# may lead to errors.

AUTO_CLASSPATH_DIR=/usr/share/java
+ AUTO_CLASSPATH_DIR=/usr/share/java

pathprepend . CLASSPATH
+ pathprepend . CLASSPATH
+ pathremove . CLASSPATH
+ local IFS=:
+ local NEWPATH
+ local DIR
+ local PATHVARIABLE=CLASSPATH
+ for DIR in ${!PATHVARIABLE}
+ '[' . '!=' . ']'
+ export CLASSPATH=
+ CLASSPATH=
+ local PATHVARIABLE=CLASSPATH
+ export CLASSPATH=.
+ CLASSPATH=.


for dir in `find ${AUTO_CLASSPATH_DIR} -type d 2>/dev/null`; do
pathappend $dir CLASSPATH
done
+ for dir in `find ${AUTO_CLASSPATH_DIR} -type d 2>/dev/null`
+ pathappend find '${AUTO_CLASSPATH_DIR}' -type d '2>/dev/null` CLASSPATH
+ pathremove find '${AUTO_CLASSPATH_DIR}'
+ local IFS=:
+ local NEWPATH
+ local DIR
+ local 'PATHVARIABLE=${AUTO_CLASSPATH_DIR}'
environment: line 4: ${AUTO_CLASSPATH_DIR}: invalid variable name

for jar in `find ${AUTO_CLASSPATH_DIR} -name "*.jar" 2>/dev/null`; do
pathappend $jar CLASSPATH
done
+ for jar in `find ${AUTO_CLASSPATH_DIR} -name "*.jar" 2>/dev/null`
+ pathappend find '${AUTO_CLASSPATH_DIR}' -name '"*.jar"' '2>/dev/null` CLASSPATH
+ pathremove find '${AUTO_CLASSPATH_DIR}'
+ local IFS=:
+ local NEWPATH
+ local DIR
+ local 'PATHVARIABLE=${AUTO_CLASSPATH_DIR}'
environment: line 4: ${AUTO_CLASSPATH_DIR}: invalid variable name

export JAVA_HOME
+ export JAVA_HOME
unset AUTO_CLASSPATH_DIR dir jar
+ unset AUTO_CLASSPATH_DIR dir jar

# End /etc/profile.d/openjdk.sh
```

In the output file also it's written invalid variable name for AUTO_CLASSPATH_DIR

I'm using bash 5.0 ( BLFS 8.4 environment )

Comment: I'm trying to install BLFS 8.4

Comment: @steeldriver how do I change it? Is there any thing that I change in the configuration script? The script is from the BLFS book how could it be wrong?

Comment: I'm using an old laptop, if it does make a difference for BLFS 8.4

Comment: Is there any way to make changes in `bash -xv /etc/profile.d/openjdk.sh`? Will it do anything?

Comment: @steeldriver In the script there is `AUTO_CLASSPATH_DIR=/usr/share/java` but no such directory is created, I also tried to create the directory manual beforehand but, the problem still persists.

Comment: OK I'm deleting my comments because clearly I don't understand your code

Comment: @steeldriver would you be kind enough to see this once http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/8.4/general/java.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I couldn't differentiate between a backtick and a single quote (because am doing this on an old laptop, I have to type in everything). I wrote the script again after this and it ran fine.